# how can I add system icons for button in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

without using any third party library how we can give system icon for button in react native.

```
<Button
   fontWeight='bold'
   backgroundColor='#3b5998'
   icon={{name: 'facebook', type: 'font-awesome'}}
   title='Connect With Facebook' />
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are using **React Native Button** component.
In that case there is no props named `icon` in `React Native Button` component.
Please refer the [documentation here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/button)

***Alternate Solution***

If you want to add a button with system icon without using any third party library you can do something like

```
<View style = {{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        paddingBottom: 30,
    }}>
        <TouchableOpacity 
            style = {{
                justifyContent: 'center',
                padding: 10,
                height: 30,
                width: '100%',
                flexDirection: 'row',
            }}
            onPress = {() => {}>
            
                <Image src={source to your image} style={{add your style}}/>
         
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
```